# How to correctly decode text files from FileSystemReadStream in Pharo 1.4

Tags: text, character-encoding, smalltalk, pharo

In Pharo 1.4 i opened a FileSystemReadStream on a text file and transformed it to a String via `aFileSystemReadStream contents asString`.

My text files are UTF8 encoded and have those Windows (CR LF) linebreaks.

The resulting Pharo Strings have two linebreaks per text file line and some weird characters instead of german umlauts like Ä, Ö, Ü etc.

How can i correctly decode my text files in Pharo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use FileSystemReadStreams in 1.4, they are not complete and buggy ;). Use FileStream instead.

```smalltalk
multiByteFileStream := FileStream fileNamed: '/foo/bar.txt'.
multiByteFileStream contents.
```

It will return a `MultiByteFileStream` where you can set the line end convention and encoding:

```smalltalk
multiByteFileStream 
    "possible values are: #cr #lf #crlf"
    lineEndConvention: #cr;
    "set a specific converter, see subclasses of TextConverter"
    converter: UTF8TextConverter new.
```

Comment: Can multiByteFileStream be combined with the rest of FileSystem, or must it be used with the old "Files" File System?

Comment: In Pharo 2.0 we overwrote `FileSystem` to use the the "old" streams. Otherwise add an extension method on `FileReference` which does something like `^ FileStream fileNamed: self fullName`